# XSLT transform with values inside namespaces

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt

I want to parse using XSLT.

My XML:

```
   <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:obtenerListaMisionesResponse xmlns:ns2="http://Servicios/">
         <return>
            <codMisiones>1</codMisiones>
            <correoMision>Foo</correoMision>
            <nombreMision>Bar</nombreMision>
         </return>
         <return>
            <codMisiones>2</codMisiones>
            <correoMision>Foo 2</correoMision>
            <nombreMision>Bar 2</nombreMision>
         </return>
      </ns2:obtenerListaMisionesResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Then I tried using this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="obtenerListaMisionesResponse">
       <xsl:for-each select="return">
            <xsl:value-of select="nombreMision"/>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I have this return:

> 1 Foo Bar 2 Foo2 Bar2

When I want this:

> Bar Bar2

I think is something because my namespace inside, but I dont understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `obtenerListaMisionesResponse` is not the same name as `ns2:obtenerListaMisionesResponse`, hence your template doesn't match it.

Try matching `ns2:obtenerListaMisionesResponse` instead, and include the `xmlns:ns2=..` declaration in your XSLT root element.